# Spring websocket - sendToUser from a cluster does not work from backup server

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

We have a spring mvc with spring websocket configured ('spring-websocket', version:'4.1.0.RELEASE').

We have a simple class that executes the following code:

```
 @Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


@Override
public void push(Long userId, Object message, WebsocketQueue queue) {

   String loginName = this.userRepository.getLoginName(userId);

   this.template.convertAndSendToUser(
                   loginName,
                   queue.getMapping(),
                   message);

}
```

This works great with a single tomcat (non clustered environment)

The problem we are facing is when working with a cluster of two tomcats.

If we try to push the message to a user from the actual tomcat he was logged in - it works.

But if we try to push the message from the other tomcat node - it does not reach the user.

1) What can we do?

2) Does changing the websocket queue names to the user login names instead of the default behavior can help us?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with [a feature added in Spring Framework 4.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.2.html#_websocket_messaging_improvements_2):

> Resolve user destinations across cluster of servers

User registries can broadcast and share their content using a specific topic destination. You can set this up by configuring the `StompBrokerRelay` for a cluster deployment; see [setUserDestinationBroadcast](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/StompBrokerRelayRegistration.html#setUserDestinationBroadcast-java.lang.String-) and [setUserRegistryBroadcast](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/StompBrokerRelayRegistration.html#setUserRegistryBroadcast-java.lang.String-).

Don't hesitate to send feedback / improvement requests on https://jira.spring.io !

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer Brian, I tried to set up both setUserDestinationBroadcast and setUserRegistryBroadcast. I fired the 2 servers, and again, instance 2 cannot send messages to instance 1 if a user is logged in originally to instance1. it seems like a subscription is made for both setUserDestinationBroadcast and setUserRegistryBroadcast but it seems that the instance2 is not publishing the failed messages for the user destination topic.. Do i have to set anything else other than these 2 parameters?